# After cutting out (with ffmpeg) a part of a music file (flac) the music player shows still the time stamps of the original file

Tags: ffmpeg, flac

I have one music file (in `flac` format). I wish to cut out a part from it.

I does it with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i file.flac -codec copy -ss 00:16:06.400 -t 158.760 result.flac
```

`ffmpeg` successfully cut the desired part of the original file, but the result still has the same time stamps.

The player (Winamp) starting the playback immediately by `00:16:06.400` and ends after the duration of `158.760 s`, see here

[image: start]

[image: end]

I naturally tested an other player (VLC media player) with the same behavior (like Winamp).

I also tested this:

```
ffmpeg -i file.flac -codec copy -ss 00:16:06.400 -t 00:18:44.360 result.flac
```

`ffmpeg` cut the original file by `00:16:06.400` until the end of the original file. I don't know why.

What do I wrong and what can one do to achive the desired result (the cut file should begin by `00:00:00.000` and end by `00:02:58.760`)?

Comment: I wouldn't bother using `-codec copy` for flac (or any losslessly compressed format)...AFAIK it's not a very "cutting-friendly" format (especially when it's not OggFLAC).

Comment: In any case, try placing `-ss 00:16:06.400 -t 158.760` before `-i`, maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By copying the audio stream you haven't altered the timestamps. You can simply re-encode the file by removing the `-codec copy` argument:

`fmpeg -i file.flac -ss 00:16:06.400 -t 00:18:44.360 result.flac`